# How to follow a car with correct rotation

Tags: unity, c#

I am making a game where car will follow a user car. I am moving use car using keyboard keys it is working fine running on my game environment roads smoothly. To follow enemy car i am using nevMesh, it correctly following but the following car/enemey car rotation is not correct. I am surprise that how do i control it? or is there any other way to acheive this thing

Comment: Look into Steering Behavior. http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/series/understanding-steering-behaviors--gamedev-12732

Comment: thanks man for helpful link it looks so hard is there any easy way?

Comment: Yeah, you should more than likely just make the rotation always go in the direction of the velocity vector of that object.

Answer (score 1):

Make the gameobject face towards is velocity vector (or its last non-zero velocity vector):

```
 float angle = Mathf.Atan2(rigidbody2D.velocity.y, rigidbody2D.velocity.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
 transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, Vector3.forward), rotateSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
```

Comment: I am using nevMesh will it allow me to get velocitiy?

Comment: Your navMesh has no concept of velocity no.  You will need to get that from the gameObject you are trying to rotate.  More then likely you have attached a rigidBody component to this gameobject, which provides you with a velocity.

Comment: if i add rigidbody to my enemey object then, i guess i will still not get the velocity as nevMesh propbably not move object using rigidbody

Comment: If you are not using a rigidBody to move your entity, then consider interpolating its movement between frames.  If you know position1, position2, and the time it took to get there, you can easily deduce the objects velocity with simple physics calculations.  You don't even need to know the velocity, you only need to know that last directino of movement really, so all you need to do is (Position2 - Position1)